# Implementation of merge sort in python3

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm taking an Algorithms course online, and the first sorting algorithm they've analysed and asked us to implement in any language of choice is merge sort.
I implemented it in python:

```
def mergeSort(arr):

    while len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        l = arr[:mid]
        r = arr[mid:]

        mergeSort(l)
        mergeSort(r)

        i = j = k = 0

        while i < len(l) and j < len(r):
            if l[i] < r[j]:
                arr[k] = l[i]
                i+=1
            else:
                arr[k] = r[j]
                j+=1
            k+=1

        while i < len(l):
            arr[k] = l[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1

        while j < len(r):
            arr[k] = r[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = [1,6,2,5,3,4]
    mergeSort(arr)
    print(arr)
```

When I execute this program, absolutely nothing is printed out. Why?

Comment: Your `mergesort` function doesn't return any value

Comment: @DOOM: `mergeSort` does not need to return a value, it performs the sort in place.

Comment: `while len(arr) > 1` is an infinite loop, since the loop body doesn't change the length of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

`mergesort` has an infinite loop for non trivial arrays.

You must change the `while len(arr) > 1:` to `if len(arr) > 1:`

Comment: Still doesn't return anything.

Comment: Wait, when i ran this code in an online ide it worked. But in VSCode it isn't returning anything